# goToAndPlay not a function?

Tags: lottie

Hi I have a tough time using the `goToAndPlay` object for Lottie. My console keeps telling me that “it’s not a function”. I’m using the latest **Lottie-interact** and **Lottie-player** libraries. Does anyone else get this issue? Thanks in advance.

[codepen attached here](https://codepen.io/mikes1025/pen/bGKeGma)

Mike

Comment: Did you read the error? Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them! Look at https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/web - `goToAndPlay` is a method on an animation instance, not a DOM node.